# How to I make this program write the changes into the original or a new copy of the input file?

Tags: python

This program works for me except the changes that are made to the input .srt (subtitle) file are displayed but NOT saved back in the input file or a new file. Can anyone please tell me what is missing? Thanks. Stuart.

code follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import sys;

# Patching SRT files to make them readable on Samsung TVs
# It basically inserts blank subtitles when silence should occur.

seqNo=1

try:
    subs = open(sys.argv[1])
except:
    print "Please provide subtile file to process"
    sys.exit(1)

while True:
    srtSeqNo=subs.readline();
    try:
        begin,arrow,end=subs.readline().rstrip('\n\r').split(" ")
    except:
        break
    srtText = subs.readline();
    again = subs.readline();
    while len(again.strip('\n\r')) > 0:
        srtText = srtText + again
        again = subs.readline()
    print "%d\n%s --> %s\n%s" % (seqNo, begin, end, srtText)

    seqNo = seqNo + 1
    print "%d\n%s --> %s\n%s\n" % (seqNo, end, end, "   ")
    seqNo = seqNo + 1
```

Comment: I can't read your code. Please, edit your question and properly format it.

Comment: Use copy paste your code then click on the code `{}` icon to indent them as code section

Comment: Open file for write, `open('file.srt', 'w')`, then write to the file object instead of print

Comment: Thanks Achillies for fixing the code layout.

Comment: Thanks Skycc. I added the open line after the import line and changed the 'print'(s) to 'write'(s) but get a syntax error on first write. As you can guess I am a novice to python. Could you please specify actual code changes required? Thanks,